# Download share point version files using Micrsoft.SharePoint.Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I am using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` DLL to upload file in my `MVC C#` project.

Now I am using below code to download **version** files, but getting file not found error.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(_SharePointSiteURL))
{
    var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(_SharePointSiteUser, securePassword);
    clientContext.RequestTimeout = 10000000;
    clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

    var spFile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(System.IO.Path.Combine("/Shared Documents/ABC", "Test.pdf"));
    clientContext.Load(spFile);
    FileVersionCollection versions = spFile.Versions;
    clientContext.Load(versions);
    var oldVersions = clientContext.LoadQuery(versions.Where(v => v != null));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    if (oldVersions != null)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion _version in oldVersions)
        {
            if (_version.VersionLabel == "2.0")
            {
                clientContext.Load(_version, item => item.Url);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                string vURL = _version.Url;
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oldFile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/" + vURL);
                clientContext.Load(oldFile);
                clientContext.Load(oldFile, item => item.ListItemAllFields);
                ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> data = oldFile.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        data.Value.CopyTo(mStream);
                        fileBytes = mStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use webservices instead? 
I hope this link help you https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/20022/9094

Comment: Do i need to install share point in my machine for this solution ? I prefer the solution which don't require to install share point and works only with proper Dlls.

Comment: No, you don't need to install sharepoint on your machine. You just need to point to webservice endpoint. Then you could use any .Net native way to work with webservices or even RestSharp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(_SharePointSiteUser, securePassword);
clientContext.RequestTimeout = 10000000;
clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials; 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(_SharePointSiteURL + "/Shared Documents/ABC/Test.pdf");
FileVersionCollection fileVersions = file.Versions; 
clientContext.Load(file); 
clientContext.Load(fileVersions);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// Download all versions of specific file as individual docs
int index = 0;
foreach (var version in fileVersions)
{
    if (version.VersionLabel == "2.0")
    {
       var str = version.OpenBinaryStream();
       clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

       string filename = string.Format("d:\\downloaded\\doc-{0}.docx", index);
       using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
       {
         str.Value.CopyTo(fs);
       }
       index++;
    }
}
```

Ensure that you are using the latest version of CSOM or alteast a version that is after September 2017 update.

Would suggest that you get the latest package of SharePoint online csom using Nuget.

Reference - [SPO CSOM September 2017](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-september-2017)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the code below to download the file versions using CSOM(C#) from SharePoint Online.

```
string _SharePointSiteURL = @"https://lz.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";

var _SharePointSiteUser = "lz@lz.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "Password";

var securePassword = new SecureString();

foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}

using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(_SharePointSiteURL))
{
    var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(_SharePointSiteUser, securePassword);
    clientContext.RequestTimeout = 10000000;
    clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web, website => website.ServerRelativeUrl, website => website.Url);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var spFile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl((web.ServerRelativeUrl.EndsWith("/") ? web.ServerRelativeUrl : web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/") + "Shared Documents/ABC/Test.pdf");
    clientContext.Load(spFile);
    FileVersionCollection versions = spFile.Versions;
    clientContext.Load(versions);
    var oldVersions = clientContext.LoadQuery(versions.Where(v => v != null));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    if (oldVersions != null)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion _version in oldVersions)
        {
            if (_version.VersionLabel == "2.0")
            {
                var localPath = @"c:\test\";
                if (!Directory.Exists(localPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);
                }

                using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {                       
                    wc.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
                    wc.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                    wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC)";
                    wc.DownloadFile(web.Url + "/" + _version.Url, localPath+"Test.pdf");
                }                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```